# Parsing HTML using BeautifulSoup, select()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the latest post contents using BeautifulSoup.
Sometimes the tag is in a recent post, sometimes it is not.
I'd like to get the tag if it's there and if it's not there, just get other texts.
My code is as below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'
url = "https:// " 
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = req.text       
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')                
link = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > a')       
title = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > div.wz-item-header > a > span')         
latest_link = link[0] # link of latest post    
latest_title = title[0].text # title of latest post

# to get the text of latest post
t_url = latest_link
t_req = requests.get(t_url, headers=headers)
t_html = c_res.text
t_soup = BeautifulSoup(t_html, 'html.parser')  
maintext = t_soup.select ('#flagArticle > div.rhymix_content.xe_content')
tag = t_soup.select_one('div.rd.clear > div.rd_body.clear > ul > li > a').get_text()

print(maintext)
print(tag)
```

The problem is, if there is no tag in the recent post, it returns error as follows.
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`
If I delete `.get_text()`from that code and the tag is not in the recent post, it returns `None`
And If the tag exists, it returns `<a href="/posts?search_target=tag&amp;search_keyword=ABC">ABC</a>`
But I want to get just `ABC`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why don't you use `try catch` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'
url = "https:// " 
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = req.text       
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')                
link = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > a')       
title = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > div.wz-item-header > a > span')         
latest_link = link[0] # link of latest post    
latest_title = title[0].text # title of latest post

# to get the text of latest post
t_url = latest_link
t_req = requests.get(t_url, headers=headers)
t_html = c_res.text
t_soup = BeautifulSoup(t_html, 'html.parser')  
maintext = t_soup.select ('#flagArticle > div.rhymix_content.xe_content')
try:
    tag = t_soup.select_one('div.rd.clear > div.rd_body.clear > ul > li > a').text
    print(tag)
except:
    print("Sure the tag exists on this page??")

print(maintext)
```

Comment: Thank you. But if the recent post doesn't have a tag, it returns error : ```print(tag)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tag' referenced before assignment```

Comment: @vantabeam please try again. modified my answer